# Graphql Schema at client side?

Tags: android, facebook, graphql, reverse-engineering, graphql-schema

I am building an android application (native - Java) and want to implement graphql based APIs.

My question is that can we share & store the schema of graphql apis at the client side just like we  do when using GRPC with protocol buffers. (I have seen small apps which are directly writing queries without having schema at client side)

Secondly, if it is possible to do so, how do we store it?

Ps: I have came across articles where people are extracting schema from facebook apk. So, I think it is possible.

Any help will be appreciated.